# FullCalendar show more link not in time order

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar, using

```
eventLimit: 2
```

Limits the number of events shown in the month view to two per day. A 'show more' link is then added, which opens a small popup showing all events. In the month view the events are shown in time order, yet in the show more pop they are instead ordered by the event id. How can I order them by time in the popup instead?

http://jsfiddle.net/obsoyuL0/

Comment: If the ordering is by ID, why can't you just re-order your IDs?

Comment: In the jsfiddle the events are held in an array but in my actual application they are returned from a database. Each id is a key for the data in the database so if someone adds an event with earlier time after a later one it will have a greater id and break the order.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find an implemented solution to your problem but to no avail. It's strange that you get that result: if you have a look at the source code of the plugin, it should be ordering the events by the start time:

```
// fullcalendar.js
// A cmp function for determining which segments should take visual priority
// DOES NOT WORK ON INVERTED BACKGROUND EVENTS because they have no eventStartMS/eventDurationMS
function compareSegs(seg1, seg2) {
    return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
        seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
        seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
        (seg1.event.title || '').localeCompare(seg2.event.title); // tie? alphabetically by title
}
```

Anyhow, there was an issue/feature request opened about [this](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364).

One solution I've come up with would be as follows: if the ids are not important in the client side and can be modified you could order the array of events by date and modify the ids accordingly:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (moment(a.start).isSame(b.start)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (moment(a.start).isBefore(b.start)) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 1;
}

events.sort(compare);

for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++) {
    events[i]['id']=i;
}
```

Then pass the ordered array to fullcalendar and the events should appear ordered by the start time in the popup.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/obsoyuL0/2/)

Comment: Great answer if id's aren't important, so thanks! Unfortunately id's from the events are used for other functionality so this is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks, what you could do is store the id in another variable inside the object, `real_id` for instance, and modify `id` to trick fullcalendar. Then use `real_id` in the rest of the application